# How do I narrow the search criteria further in the Reg Ex?

Tags: python, regex

File/variable contains the  following lines.

```
Interface wlan1-cabin-2  
ifindex 37  
wdev 0x300000003  
addr 06:53:1a:4e:07:02  
ssid SSID3  
type AP  
channel 6 (2437 MHz), width: 20 MHz, center1: 2437 MHz
```

---

```
ssid_regex = re.compile("wdev +0x300000003((.*\n){2})", re.MULTILINE)
```

returns 2 lines below `wdev 0x300000003` as expected.

How can the expression be further modified to obtain a match for `ssid` and the value after the space which is `SSID3`?

Comment: why not split the matched strings with `space` ?

Answer (score 1):

Here's another solution.

```
import re

interface_info = '''Interface wlan1-cabin-2  
ifindex 37  
wdev 0x300000003 
addr 06:53:1a:4e:07:02    
ssid SSID3  
type AP  
channel 6 (2437 MHz), width: 20 MHz, center1: 2437 MHz'''

mac_address = re.search(r'(addr)\s.+', interface_info)
ssid_match = re.search(r'(ssid)\s.+', interface_info)
interface_type = re.search(r'(type)\s.+',interface_info)
channel_info = re.search(r'(channel).+',interface_info)
split_channel_info = re.split(r'\,', channel_info.group(0))

print (str(mac_address.group(0)).lstrip('addr'))
print (str(ssid_match.group(0)).lstrip('ssid'))
print (str(interface_type.group(0)).lstrip('type'))

print(str(split_channel_info[0]).strip())
print(str(split_channel_info[1]).strip())
print(str(split_channel_info[2]).strip())
```

Here's the other solution that was previously suggested.

```
import re

interface_info = '''Interface wlan1-cabin-2  
ifindex 37  
wdev 0x300000003  
addr 06:53:1a:4e:07:02 
ssid SSID3  
type AP  
channel 6 (2437 MHz), width: 20 MHz, center1: 2437 MHz'''

interface_regex = re.compile('wdev +0x300000003(.*)\naddr(.*)\nssid(.*)\ntype(.*)\nchannel(.*)')
interface_extract = re.search(interface_regex,interface_info)
interface_split = re.split(r'\n', interface_extract.group(0))

mac_address = str(interface_split[1]).strip('addr')
ssid = str(interface_split[2]).strip('ssid')
interface_type = str(interface_split[3]).strip('type')
channel_info = interface_split[4]
split_channel_info = re.split(r'\,', channel_info)
```

Comment: so just to get SSID3, would it be group(1) or group(2)?

Comment: I have updated my answer on how I would accomplish the task related to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Add a match for that line to the regexp.

```
ssid_regex = re.compile("wdev +0x300000003\n(.*)\nssid\s+(.*)")
```

In the result, group 1 will contain the `addr` line, group 2 will contain `SSID3`.

There's no need for `re.MULTILINE` since you never use `^` or `$` in the regexp.

Comment: I corrected the file which was missing the `addr` line.

Comment: I changed the order of the matches in the regexp.

Comment: Thank you. I corrected the file which was missing the `addr` line. I tried by adding another \n.  ssid_regex = re.compile("wdev +0x300000003\n\n\s*ssid\s+(.*)\n(.*)"). It did not return the ssid I was expecting. How should I correct the one you initially posted?

Comment: I got this error. #@%FAIL%@# Unhandled exception raised: <AttributeError> '_sre.SRE_Pattern' object has no attribute 'group'
  
    ssid_regex = re.compile("wdev +0x300000003\n(.*)\nssid\s+(.*)").group(2)

Comment: You're calling `.group()` on the wrong object. You're calling it on the pattern object instead of the `match` object that `search()` returns.

Comment: `ssid_regex.search(text).group(2)`

Comment: Didn't you realize that you never passed the text you're trying to match to the regexp?

Comment: I am passing the text through a variable in the code which is not shown here. I was able to implement the code for what I was trying to achieve.

Comment: I meant in the code you pasted in the comment. It never passes the text there.